# Laravel add avatar in user registration

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form right now that is working great. Basically I am adding users and based off the form they are assigned a role. Great. But now I am trying to add an avatar to the user table under the column "avatar". What I have found makes sense but not working, getting the error "Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::hasFile() should not be called statically"

AuthController.php

```
//imports
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//create method
protected function create(array $data)
    {



        //Creat the user
        $create = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first-name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last-name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'avatar' => $data['avatar'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        //Is it a User? Then give them that role
        if ($data['form'] == 'user')
        {
            $user = User::find($create->id);

            $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'user')->firstOrFail();

            $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
        }

        //Is it an Admin? Then give them that role
        if ($data['form'] == 'admin')
        {
            $user = User::find($create->id);

            $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'owner')->firstOrFail();

            $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
        }

        //Did they upload an Avatar
        if (Request::HasFile('avatar'))
        {

            $file = Request::file('avatar');
            $img_path   = '/uploads/avatars/';

            $image_name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move(public_path() . $img_path, $image_name);

            $image_alter = Image::make(sprintf(public_path() . $img_path . '%s', $image_name))->resize(75, 75)->save();

            $user->avatar = $image_name; // Note we add the image path to the databse field before the save.

        }

        return $create;
    }
```

Comment: by the way  you have this line twice, its useless i think since you can use the same $user `$user = User::find($create->id);`

Answer (score 2):

That's a standard PHP error message. You are calling the method statically, that is, invoking it from the class (`Request::hasFile()`).
You should invoke it from an instance of the class Request.
You can get that instance by calling the service container:

```
protected function create(array $data){
    // ...
    $request = app('request');

    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {

    // ...
```

(It's probably more natural having the Request instance injected as a controller method parameter. This works when you do it in the method called by the framework routing. I suggest this other way because you are calling an internal method yourself.)

Comment: more like a duplicate answer to me with better explaining

Comment: Neither solution worked, Getting a new error of "Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist". I will repost the question with current code and new error

Comment: thats probably a ; missing or something, its not a big deal i guess

Comment: @Packy The code you are copying doesn't declare the class. Did you miss some lines in the copy-paste?

Comment: @Packy Silly question, I know you are probably just copying the relevant parts. But just in case

Comment: From the docs I read in Laravel adding `Request $request` is all you need to do in the function to use `$request->hasFile('avatar')`

Comment: @Packy Yes, but: who is calling your method `create`? And what's the `data` parameter?

Comment: The method is called by my route on POST and the data is a laravel function that grabs the form data. The form works fine if I get rid of the Request and Avatar stuff

Comment: Ok, the AuthController as it comes in the Laravel package calls the `create` method internally. You can overwrite it as you are doing, but you cannot simply change the parameters it receives. That's why injecting the Request as parameter won't work in this case. (Check out the `RegistersUsers` trait, that's where.)

Answer (score 0):

try to add the request to the method

```
 protected function create(Request $request, array $data){
//code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `use Request;` instead of `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 0):

See below  code. It works for me.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $request = app('request');

    if($request->hasfile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );
    } 
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'avatar' => $filename,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

See details code here : http://www.pranms.com/how-to-add-avatar-field-in-the-registration-form-in-laravel-5-2/